# Show and hide a field depending of a selection from another field rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I would like to know if there is any way to hide or show a field in rails admin based in a **real-time selection**, for example: I have a form for a channel, where i can select the list of users that i want to include to that channel.And if its public i dont want to show the field with that list of users. Here a leave an example of the view: [Display the table users only when the scope is private](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVnXM.jpg)

Is there any way to hide it and show it in "real-time"? (Depending on scope)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically show/hide Rails form fields using CoffeeScript and JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873886/how-to-dynamically-show-hide-rails-form-fields-using-coffeescript-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. Rails admin does not provide any configuration to make this possible out of the box.

Long answer yes, you can build your own custom fields with your own javascript logic to dynamically display data.